# cypher query without any return rows after modifying it using pattern comprehension

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This cypher query on the neo4j movie dataset will return 822 rows

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE m.year = 2000
AND a.born IS NOT NULL
RETURN DISTINCT a.name AS Actor, a.born AS Born
order by a.born
```

I modify the query using pattern comprehension below and it returns 15443  rows, but all of them are empty arrays.

```
MATCH (a:Actor)
with a, [ (a where a.born is not null)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie where m.year = 2000)  | a.name ] as Actors
return Actors
```

My intent is to return a list of actors just like the first query. What went wrong in the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This will give you the distinct actors:

```
WITH [(a:Actor WHERE a.born IS NOT NULL)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie WHERE m.year = 2000)|a.name] AS actorList
UNWIND actorList AS actor
RETURN DISTINCT actor
```

Comment: this gives only one row return

Comment: I updated my answer to return each distinct actor in a separate row.